# How come my enqueued class is still getting executed in my unit test when I never call start/stopTest methods?

Tags: unit-test, asynchronous, queueable-apex

Per salesforce docs (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm):

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected
>   by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes
>   are run synchronously.

I thought NOT calling start/stop would mean the async stuff wasn't collected and didn't run.  In fact, I'm pretty sure I witnessed that being the case in the past.

But now I've got a unit test that never calls Test.startTest()/Test.stopTest(), but it invokes code that enqueues a job and the job is still running.  I'm trying to write a *unit* test that *just* tests the code that enqueues the job, and I don't want to deal with setting everything up so that the enqueued job actually succeeds.  I'll test the job itself in a different unit test.

Simple way to reproduce the issue:

```
@IsTest
public class EnqueueUnitTestIssue {
    private class FailEnqueued implements Queueable {
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            System.assert(false);
        }

    }
    @IsTest
    static void testEnqueuedStillExecuted() {
        System.enqueueJob(new FailEnqueued());
    }
}
```

This unit test will fail at the "System.assert(false);" line.

Has it always been this way?  Could have sworn things didn't work this way in the past.

Comment: It's been that way for *at least* two years, possibly longer (and nobody noticed it). I've linked the related Q&A for you. If you need any further assistance, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose I'll just mock the enqueue call as well then...